# Disassembler logic for custom opcodes in C

Tags: c, assembly, binary, disassembly, binary-data

So I'm building a disassembler that will convert a file containing hexadecimal data into assembly language.

So from this format I could convert the hexadecimal data in the file into decimal using uint8_t and store them in an array. Then I decided to bit shift the last number in the array to get number of instructions of the last function; essentially I'm parsing backwards since I don't know how much padding there are at the beginning and the number of ops in a function is given at the end of the function. But then I realised that the operations varies in bit size and aren't in perfect 8 or 16 bit bounds. So then I was stuck since my array, using the example at the top, was essentially this:

uint8_t hex[] = {0x00, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x42, 0x82, 0x86, 0x04, 0x10, 0x45};

So can anyone help me with the logic in parsing? This is my first time posting so I'm sorry if I'm missing anything and will provide more information or delete if needed

Comment: The instructions vary in size, but the opcodes are all three bits. So if you mask out the other bits in a byte, you know the opcode, and from that you can infer what data values follow. And then you need to shift and mask the appropriate number of bits (sometimes from 2 bytes because they're not aligned) to get the values. And you repeat this process for every instruction. This is no different from other disassemblers. If you run into issues with that, post the code your trying and people might be able to help.

Comment: Just curious, what is this assembly language used for?

Comment: hi @EmanuelP thank you for your response, that is exactly what I'm trying to do :D but I am stuck on this part of what you said "And then you need to shift and mask the appropriate number of bits (sometimes from 2 bytes because they're not aligned) to get the values". How would you shift between bytes? for instance, I am shifting 3 bits left then right on the last element in the array to get the nubmer of operations for the last function and then shifting the second to last element in the array 5 bits left then right to find the opcode, but the values go across elements in the array.

Comment: @potatopppcccccc You can shift to bytes together by combining it with an bitwise or. If you, for example have b1 from which you need the high order 4 bits, you would shift them to the right 4 place. And if you need the low order 4 bits from b2 you shift them left, eg `(b1 >> 4) | (b2 << 4)`. Now you have 8 bits in a byte representing the number that crossed the byte boundary. And you need to be careful that you only include those bits that you need, which if needed is done with bit masks.

Comment: Instead of shifting and masking (which I think would be really complicated) what if you convert the uint8_t array into an array of bits - it uses a lot more memory but you can access individual bits much easier.

Comment: @EmanuelP ooooooh I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @JerryJeremiah are you saying like int bins[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, etc}?

Comment: You can certainly do it with masking and shifting but I think it would be more complicated than an array of 1s and 0s  - I posted an answer that does it that way.  Have a look and decide which is more complicated...

Comment: is there are a reason why you are bitpacking all of this?  use a 32 bit value for each instruction either left or right justify and leave the rest of the bits as padding, then it is one word per instruction, no need for how many instructions in a function, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of shifting and masking (which I think would be really complicated) what if you convert the uint8_t array into an array of bits - it uses a lot more memory but you can access individual bits much easier.

Here is a sample program that does this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t getBits(uint8_t *bits, uint8_t size, uint32_t *index)
{
    uint8_t value = 0;
    *index -= size; // decrement index to the starting point
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        value = (value<<1) | bits[*index+i];
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    // sample program
    uint8_t array[] = {0x00,0x03,0x02,0x01,0x42,0x82,0x86,0x04,0x10,0x45};
    
    // program with zero padding
    // uint8_t array[] = {0xE8,0x39,0x06,0xA0,0xC4,0x16,0x82,0x90,0x4A,0x08,0x41};
    
    uint32_t array_size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); // 10 bytes
    uint32_t bits_size = 8*array_size; // 80 bytes
    uint8_t* bits = malloc(bits_size);
    
    for(uint32_t a=0;a<array_size;a++)
        for(uint32_t b=0;b<8;b++)
            bits[a*8+b] = (array[a] >> (7-b)) & 1;
    
    puts("Binary program file:");
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<bits_size;i++)
        printf("%s%d",(i%8?"":" "),bits[i]);
    puts("");
    
    enum                    {  MOV,  CAL,  RET,  REF,  ADD,  PRINT,  NOT,  EQU};
    uint8_t params[]      = {    2,    1,    0,    2,    2,      1,    1,    1};
    const char *opcodes[] = {"MOV","CAL","RET","REF","ADD","PRINT","NOT","EQU"};

    enum                    {  VAL,  REG,  STK,  PTR};
    uint8_t value_size[]  = {    8,    3,    5,    5};
    const char *types[]   = {"VAL","REG","STK","PTR"};

    uint32_t index = bits_size; // start at end
    
    // minimum program size is function(3) + opcode(3) + size(5)
    // if there are less than that number of bits then it must be padding
    while(index>10)
    {
        uint8_t size = getBits(bits,5,&index);
        printf("\nsize=%d\n",size);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            for(int o=0; o<size; o++)
            {
                uint8_t opcode = getBits(bits,3,&index);
                printf("opcode=%s",opcodes[opcode]);
                
                for(int p=0; p<params[opcode]; p++)
                {
                    printf("%c ",p?',':':');
                    
                    uint8_t type = getBits(bits,2,&index);
                    printf("type=%s ",types[type]);
                    
                    uint8_t value = getBits(bits,value_size[type],&index);
                    printf("value=%d",value);
                }
                
                puts("");
            }
        
            uint8_t function = getBits(bits,3,&index);
            printf("function=%d\n",function);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/S1qVStz8d

**How it `getBits()` works:**

You make an array of individual digits from the original value, and then you take bits from it one at a time to make a new value - `getBits()` is the function I have written for that.

To understand how it works imagine how it works in base 10: `321` is put into the array `{3,2,1}` and you could turn it back into a value with:

```
value = 0;
value = value*10 + digits[0];
value = value*10 + digits[1];
value = value*10 + digits[2];
```

Which gives `(((0)*10+3)*10+2)*10+1` which is `321`

If `5` (binary `101`) is put into the array `{1,0,1}`, you could turn it back into a value with:

```
value = 0;
value = value*2 + bits[0];
value = value*2 + bits[1];
value = value*2 + bits[2];
```

Which gives `(((0)*2+1)*2+0)*2+1` which is `5` (binary `101`)

And that **does** work.  And a decent compiler would optimize the `*2` into `<<1` and the `+` into `|`, but you could do it yourself (which is what I did):

```
value = 0;
value = (value<<1) | bits[0];
value = (value<<1) | bits[1];
value = (value<<1) | bits[2];
```

Which produces that same binary `00000101`

It's just a readability thing - with decimal you expect to see `value*10+x` but with binary you expect to see bit operations like shift/or instead of math operations like multiply/add.

Then, if you use a loop with a size and an index that points to the end of the array, you get:

```
uint8_t value = 0;
index -= size; // decrement index to the starting point
for(uint32_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    value = (value<<1) | bits[index+i];
```

But, of course, if it is a function then index needs to be a pointer and you need to dereference it everywhere:

```
uint8_t getBits(uint8_t *bits, uint8_t size, uint32_t *index)
{
    uint8_t value = 0;
    *index -= size; // decrement index to the starting point
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        value = (value<<1) | bits[*index+i];
    return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, can you please explain how getBits works? I'm a bit confused on it especially value = (value<<1) | bits[*index+i];

Comment: @potatopppcccccc Have a look at the edit I've made to the answer.  Let me know if that explains it well enough - if not I will break it down a bit further.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but that explains it perfectly. Thank you very much